# How to call dynamically/parametrize the Flutter Windows runner main.cpp

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, widgetbook

**Context :**

A Flutter desktop app uses two important packages. BitsDojo for handling the main window app + WidgetBook for managing the widget UI. Each package need their own entrypoint.dart file at startup (like 2 app in the same project).

**Issue :**

BitsDojo package needs to add 2 lines in the main.cpp file for running because it's change behaviour of the window app into Windows OS.

*BUT*

WidgetBook don't run if those added lines into main.cpp exist. If I remove this added widgetbook app run correctly.

**Questions :**

- How can I launch the main.cpp file with parameter ?
- How can I read external variable into main.cpp from Dart or Flutter run command ?
- What other kind of solution can I implement to resolve this constraint ?
- Is there possible to read a --dart-define variable value into main.cpp file ?

**the <project_dir>/windows/runner/main.cpp with added bitsDojo package lines :**

```
#include <bitsdojo_window_windows/bitsdojo_window_plugin.h>
auto bdw = bitsdojo_window_configure(BDW_CUSTOM_FRAME | BDW_HIDE_ON_STARTUP);
```

**the entrypoint for main app :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:beamer/beamer.dart';
import 'package:bitsdojo_window/bitsdojo_window.dart';

import './config/router.dart';
import './config/service_locator.dart';


Future<void> main() async
{
  setupLocator();

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MyApp());

  doWhenWindowReady(()
  {
    final win         = appWindow;
    const initialSize = Size(500, 249.7);
    win.size          = initialSize;
    win.alignment     = Alignment.center;
    win.show();
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
{
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp.router(

      routeInformationParser: BeamerParser(),
      routerDelegate: routerDelegate,
      title: 'Title APP',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

**the entrypoint for widgetbook app :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:widgetbook/widgetbook.dart';
import 'package:widgetbook_annotation/widgetbook_annotation.dart' as widgetbook;

import 'widgetbook.directories.g.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(const WidgetbookApp());
}

@widgetbook.App()
class WidgetbookApp extends StatelessWidget
{
  const WidgetbookApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Widgetbook.material
    (
      directories: directories,
    );
  }
}
```

I also use a --dart-define parameter for launching my app with different flavor...

**I also try to get/set ENV_VAR like this but I have many syntax errors for C++ that don't understand (I'm not C++ dev) :**

set ENV_VAR into "run configurations" parameters : FLUTTER_LAUNCHED_APP=main

FLUTTER_LAUNCHED_APP=main

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstdlib>

#include <flutter/dart_project.h>
#include <flutter/flutter_view_controller.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "flutter_window.h"
#include "utils.h"

// BITSDOJO package add-ons
const char *GetEnv(const char *tag, const char *def = nullptr) noexcept
{
    const char *ret = std::getenv(tag);
    return ret ? ret :
    def;
}

//int ret = 0;
if (getEnvVar("FLUTTER_LAUNCHED_APP"))
{
    cout << "FLUTTER_LAUNCHED_APP enable ! ";
    #include <bitsdojo_window_windows/bitsdojo_window_plugin.h>
    auto bdw = bitsdojo_window_configure(BDW_CUSTOM_FRAME | BDW_HIDE_ON_STARTUP);
}
else
{
    cout << "FLUTTER_LAUNCHED_APP disable ! ";
}

//return (-1==ret?errno:0);
```

Thank you for all your suggest and help !